# Chrome highlighting a div with tabindex="-1"

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, tabindex

I am using a React component that injects a `<div tabindex="-1">` on my HTML. Then, every time I click an inner object it adds a blue border on the element, like the example below:

https://jsfiddle.net/zdtw7uq0/

Is it possible to remove this border?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) to turn the behavior off.

For all element with `tabindex`:

```
[tabindex] {
  outline: none;
}
```

Only for elements with `tabindex="-1"`:

```
[tabindex="-1"] {
  outline: none;
}
```

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 100px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

[tabindex="-1"] {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div tabindex="-1">
  <div class="container">
    Something
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Code:

```
<div tabindex="-1" class="tab">
  <div class="container">
    Something
  </div>
</div>
```

Style:

```
.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 200px;
  background-color: #fff;
  outline:none;
}

.tab {
  outline:none;
}
```